# Заявки товаров с разными идентификаторомами

Tags: php, html, форма

Мне нужно сделать простой список товаров, при котором человек при клике на карточку выскакивало модальное окно и заказчик мог заполнить форму и данные с этой формы ушли на емаил, но при этом что-бы на емаил можно было понять какой именно товар был заказан.

Тоесть на сайте не нужны вещи как в интернет магазине на подобие корзины, просто обычная форма заявки которая отправляеться на емаил. Кто нибудь знает как в этом случае сделать что-бы к php обработчику прикреплялось поле с обзначением товара?

Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 0):

Как помню, читал где-то:

> в javascript'е всего три модальных окна - alert (), confirm (), prompt
>   ()

То есть, эффект модального окна нужно реализовывать самому, через, например, `div`.

Который должен быть поверх всего содержимого страницы, далее, в этом div'е создаем нашу форму и делаем одно поле с типом `hidden`, имя например `product_page` или `product_id`, а его значение - адрес страницы, или идентификатор товара, соответственно.

**P. S.** Могу написать Вам пример, но может Вы сами попробуете? Если не получится, готов помочь ;)